# hover on anchor tag element with image to appear only on hover

Tags: html, css

i wanna add that "arrow-down" image on hovering anchor tag element,like shown in the below image. how to achieve that?

[image]

here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ACHIEVEMENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AWARDS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PUBLICATIONS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MEDIA</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .menu{float:left;margin-left:1%;}
 .menu ul li{list-style:none;float:left;margin-right:18px;}
 .menu ul li:last-child{margin-right:0;}
 .menu ul li a{text-decoration:none;color:#fff; font-family: 'OpenSansSemibold';font-size:14px;border-bottom:3px solid transparent;padding-bottom:5px;}
 .menu ul li a:hover{background:url("images/arrow-down.png")no-repeat 50% 100%;border-bottom:3px solid #fff;}
```

Comment: It might br help you:   https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Balvant Ahir's response

After you've digged up art of [css trianlges](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

You can use pseudo elements to create a triangle, css below

```
.menu ul li a:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -3px;
}
```

The arrow is absolutely positioned, so need to set position relative on the link itself

```
.menu ul li a {
    position: relative;
}
```

That and playing around with `display:none` and `display:block` on hover

```
.menu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
}

.menu ul li a:hover:after {
    display: block;
}
```

Should be enough

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/6sa3a4k4/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ? Don't go for image when you have `css` to do the job. Check the additional styles.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4ukdvjjc/1/)**

```css
.menu ul {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 18px;
}
.menu ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'OpenSansSemibold';
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
  background: url("images/arrow-down.png")no-repeat 50% 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
/*  additional styles */

.menu {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background: #3272B8;
}
.menu:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
.menu li {
  position: relative;
}
.menu li a:after {
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid #fff;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  visibility: hidden;
}
.menu li a:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">PROFILE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ACHIEVEMENTS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">AWARDS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">PUBLICATIONS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">MEDIA</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```